# OpenCV: Is it possible to detect rectangle from corners?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

I have a photo where a person holds a sheet of paper.  I'd like to detect the rectangle of that sheet of paper.

[image]

I have tried following different tutorials from OpenCV and various SO answers and sample code for detecting squares / rectangles, but the problem is that they all rely on contours of some kind.

If I follow the `squares.cpp` example, I get the following results from contours:

[image]

As you can see, the fingers are part of the contour, so the algorithm does not find the square.

I, also, tried using `HoughLines()` approach, but I get similar results to above:

[image]

I can detect the corners, reliably though:

[image]

There are other corners in the image, but I'm limiting total corners found to < 50 and the corners for the sheet of paper are **always** found.

Is there some algorithm for finding a rectangle from multiple corners in an image?  I can't seem to find an existing approach.

Comment: Basically, you'll want to get the contours, feed them to `appoxPolyDP()`, then check the resulting `approxCurve` size. If it's 4, you've got a quadrilateral, and those are your corners. You will likely have to re-arrange the ordering of the corners afterwards, as the ordering isn't guaranteed. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I tried that but the outline of the fingers breaks the side edges of the sheet of paper and appoxPolyDP doesn't find it then.

Comment: I'm not sure, then. Could you loop over the contours checking for a 90° angle?

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'm not sure how I would match up the corners to each other.

Comment: photoshop the hands off,  then automate this

Comment: use cv::minAreaRect to find a rotated rectangle enclosing all 4 points. Use convexHull for perspectively distorted rectangle corners

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can apply a morphological filter to close the gaps in your edge image. Then if you find the contours, you can detect an inner closed contour as shown below. Then find the convexhull of this contour to get the rectangle.

Closed edges:

[image: closed]

Contour:

[image: contour]

Convexhull:

[image: hull]

In the code below I've just used an arbitrary kernel size for morphological filter and filtered out the contour of interest using an area ratio threshold. You can use your own criteria instead of those.

Code

```
Mat im = imread("Sh1Vp.png", 0); // the edge image
Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(11, 11));
Mat morph;
morphologyEx(im, morph, CV_MOP_CLOSE, kernel);

int rectIdx = 0;
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(morph, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++)
{
    RotatedRect rect = minAreaRect(contours[idx]);
    double areaRatio = abs(contourArea(contours[idx])) / (rect.size.width * rect.size.height);
    if (areaRatio > .95)
    {
        rectIdx = idx;
        break;
    }
}
// get the convexhull of the contour
vector<Point> hull;
convexHull(contours[rectIdx], hull, false, true);

// visualization
Mat rgb;
cvtColor(im, rgb, CV_GRAY2BGR);
drawContours(rgb, contours, rectIdx, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
for(size_t i = 0; i < hull.size(); i++)
{
    line(rgb, hull[i], hull[(i + 1)%hull.size()], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
}
```